# How useful is JavaScript without its third-party libraries i.e. JQuery etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, w3c

I'm new to JavaScript, and just started learning about Document Object Model.

I came to an understanding that DOM is actually not a "core/default" library of JavaScript rather developed by W3.org as a programmatic model to work with HTML.

I have also learnt that JQuery is also a library built ON TOP of JavaScript just like AngularJS NodeJSN etc.

**So my question is:**
Does Javascript have a core library? 
And is JavaScript actually useful without relying on third-party libraries in 2015?

Are there examples of programs/products that just use Javascript without any third-party libraries?

Comment: Have you read i.e. the jQuerry start page and the about section? Have you used Goog?

Comment: Keep in mind that all of those third-party libraries are built using JavaScript so you can do all of the same things yourself with vanilla JavaScript. The libraries just make it easier.

Comment: jQuery handles pretty well in a single line of code what would take you several if not hundreds of lines in vanilla JS to support vendor specific browsers and older browsers. Yes, still in 2015

Comment: @JustinNiessner - nice to see that kind of comment. More constructive than "just do your own research". It's an unsuitable question for SO, but it's nice to see OP was greeted right regardless.

Answer (score 6):

There is a set of **core** JavaScript functions, and a [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) to detail these functions and their behaviors. This is sometimes known as ECMAScript and common support is for version 5 (aka es-5).

There are a great number of functions available to you in here, from DOM manipulation, creating/modifying arrays and even HTTP requests. Essentially every library that you see, is just a wrapper on top of the core JavaScript functionality to make your life easier.

A great example of this is http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ which gives examples of how to do things in `vanilla` JavaScript. Here's a simple comparison from their site:

**has class in jQuery**

```
$(el).hasClass(className);
```

**has class in pure JavaScript**

```
if (el.classList)
  el.classList.contains(className);
else
  new RegExp('(^| )' + className + '( |$)', 'gi').test(el.className);
```

This quite clearly shows how jQuery can make things easier, but you can also achieve what you want in pure JavaScript.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I'd argue that "DOM manipulation and HTTP requests" belong to core javascript(ecmascript) as there is not only browser side javascript(node.js)

Comment: @let4be that's what I said didn't I? Those are things that pure JavaScript supports (which typically you see wrapped up in a library). Do I need to re-word to make clearer or have I mis-understood?

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me. I had a feeling this question might get down voted but I had to ask! Can you please check the link to the example, it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3289740 which link are you having trouble with? I've tried both of them and they're fine on my machine. Could be a firewall issue?

Comment: @user3289740 by the way, if you feel a question may get downvoted you might want to consider how you can make it more targeted. If you get several downvoted questions your account will be automatically blocked from asking further questions on the site. This also takes into account deleted questions, so be careful!

Comment: Site's down for me, here's a cache http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:o5UxvpFx0RIJ:youmightnotneedjquery.com/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca

Comment: @TankorSmash weird - works fine for me even with a force refresh in my browser.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Javascript have a core library?

The language itself doesn't have any means of interacting with anything. It relies on being run in an environment where it can interface with something useful, for example running in a browser and interfacing with the DOM objects.

JavaScript is also used in environments completely different from a browser, like in the web server platform [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) where the environment allows JavaScript to respond to web requests and access system resources.

> Is JavaScript actually useful without relying on third-party libraries
>   in 2015?

Yes. You can do anything without a third party library that you can do with one, you just need to write more code yourself. Third party libraries are only used for convenience.